# NHibernate IsLoaded and Load for child collections like in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am busy adapting the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` project to instead use NHibernate for the ORM. It has been fairly easy, with a lot of changes adding `async` variants for various EF methods where NH has no built-in async.

My biggest concern so far is with code like the following for this (much abridged) `DbAspNetUsers` class:

```
public partial class DbAspNetUsers : IDomainEntity<String>  
{
    ...
    public virtual IList<DbAspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaimsList{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now elsewhere, in the original EF `UserStore` class (hence some name differences), and for more properties than just claims, we have code like the following:

```
private async Task EnsureClaimsLoaded(TUser user)
{
    if (!Context.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.Claims).IsLoaded)
    {
        var userId = user.Id;
        await _userClaims.Where(uc => uc.UserId.Equals(userId)).LoadAsync().WithCurrentCulture();
        Context.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.Claims).IsLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

The NH XML mapping for claims is as follows:

```
<class name="DbAspNetUsers, Core.Data" table="AspNetUsers" lazy='true'>
  ...
  <bag name="AspNetUserClaimsList" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy='true'>
    <key column="UserId" />
    <one-to-many class="DbAspNetUserClaims, Core.Data" />
  </bag>
  ...
</class>
```

Does NHibernate have any functionality to cover scenarios like this, or should I simply write methods that do the work of EF's `LoadAsync`, and then set a `Loaded` flag, repeated for each child collection?

Any suggestions, commands, or just advice on how to handle this in NH if I can would be greatly appreciated, as would even being convincingly told I cannot do this and must simply load each entity as needed.

Please excuse the terrible naming. I'm using the 'official' mappings generator for the office.

Comment: Would `NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(user.Claims)` do?  As for loading the lazy collection, you could either do `NHibernateUtil.Initialize()` or simply start using the collection (e.g. calling `user.Claims.Count()` would cause NH to fetch the collection for you)

Comment: Thanks, @NPras, I was not aware of `IsInitialized` et al, but I'm sure they are what I'm looking for. I will check and you can make this an answer to be accepted.

Comment: Can't you make sure that the collection is initialized when loading the users with eager loading? It looks cumbersome to me remembering to call EnsureCollectionXIsLoaded everytime CollectionX is used.

Comment: @Firo I am writing a fork of three Identity assemblies to use NHibernate instead of EF, so I am strictly trying to not go near any logic, only data access. Changing to eager loading would be effectively changing the logic, even if it is in the DAL.

Comment: @NPras, why not answer with that information?

Comment: Ha, thanks for the kind reminder.  I wasn't sure they were the correct equivalent, as I haven't actually used EF that much. Also, I missed your first comment :)

Answer (score 0):

`NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(user.Claims)` would give you an idea whether your lazy collection has been loaded.

As for actually loading them, you could either do `NHibernateUtil.Initialize()` or simply start using the collection (e.g. calling `user.Claims.Count()` would cause NH to fetch the collection for you)